# Each line on a new row in excel

Tags: excel, newline, delimiter

I have around 3000 sequences in a notepad. eg:

> gi|16802049|ref|NP_463534.1| chromosomal replication initiation protein [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MQSIEDIWQETLQIVKKNMSKPSYDTWMKSTTAHSLEGNTFIISAPNNFVRDWLEKSYTQFIANILQEIT
>   GRLFDVRFIDGEQEENFEYTVIKPNPALDEDGIEIGKHMLNPRYVFDTFVIGSGNRFAHAASLAVAEAPA
>   KAYNPLFIYGGVGLGKTHLMHAVGHYVQQHKDNAKVMYLSSEKFTNEFISSIRDNKTEEFRTKYRNVDVL
>   LIDDIQFLAGKEGTQEEFFHTFNTLYDEQKQIIISSDRPPKEIPTLEDRLRSRFEWGLITDITPPDLETR
>   IAILRKKAKADGLDIPNEVMLYIANQIDSNIRELEGALIRVVAYSSLVNKDITAGLAAEALKDIIPSSKS
>   QVITISGIQEAVGEYFHVRLEDFKAKKRTKSIAFPRQIAMYLSRELTDASLPKIGDEFGGRDHTTVIHAH
>   EKISQLLKTDQVLKNDLAEIEKNLRKAQNMF
>
> gi|16802050|ref|NP_463535.1| DNA polymerase III subunit beta [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MKFVIERDRLVQAVNEVTRAISARTTIPILTGIKIVVNDEGVTLTGSDSDISIEAFIPLIENDEVIVEVE
>   SFGGIVLQSKYFGDIVRRLPEENVEIEVTSNYQTNISSGQASFTLNGLDPMEYPKLPEVTDGKTIKIPIN
>   VLKNIVRQTVFAVSAIEVRPVLTGVNWIIKENKLSAVATDSHRLALREIPLETDIDEEYNIVIPGKSLSE
>   LNKLLDDASESIEMTLANNQILFKLKDLLFYSRLLEGSYPDTSRLIPTDTKSELVINSKAFLQAIDRASL
>   LARENRNNVIKLMTLENGQVEVSSNSPEVGNVSENVFSQSFTGEEIKISFNGKYMMDALRAFEGDDIQIS
>   FSGTMRPFVLRPKDAANPNEILQLITPVRTY
>
> gi|16802051|ref|NP_463536.1| hypothetical protein lmo0003 [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MMKDMTTGNPTKLIFLFAMPMLIGNLFQQFYTMIDAVIVGKFVSVDALAAVGATNSVNFFMISLIIGLMS
>   GISVVVAQYFGFKDYDRLKDVIATATYAVVFSAIILTVAGVLLAKPLLILLRTPANILDDSTIFLTTLFI
>   GILPMSLYNGMAAILRALGNSITPLIFLILSSLMNIALDFLFVVYMDMGVRGAAIATVLSQTAAAIAVIY
>   YAYRHVPFMRIERAKFKLSTPLLKEMVRIGLPSGLQGSFISIGNMALQSLINGFGSSVVAAYTAASRIDS
>   LTYQPGIAFGAASSMFAGQNIGAGKIDRVREGFWSGIKVVTAISIGITILVQLFARQFLLLFVDSSETEV
>   INIGVSYLLIVSLFYVVVGILFVVRETLRGTGDAMVPLAMGIFELVSRLVIGFVLSLYIGYVGLWWATPV
>   AWITATILGVWRYKSGAWQKKAVIRRK

I am trying to paste this in an excel sheet but each sequence is split into parts and put on each row. Is there a way of setting the new line as a delimiter when I am copying into a column so that each sequence data will lie in a single row rather than each line on each row. Please do ask if there are any questions.

I would like to have one sequence in a single line.. eg:

> gi|16802049|ref|NP_463534.1| chromosomal replication initiation protein [Listeria monocytogenes EGD-e]
>   MQSIEDIWQETLQIVKKNMSKPSYDTWMKSTTAHSLEGNTFIISAPNNFVRDWLEKSYTQFIANILQEIT
>   GRLFDVRFIDGEQEENFEYTVIKPNPALDEDGIEIGKHMLNPRYVFDTFVIGSGNRFAHAASLAVAEAPA
>   KAYNPLFIYGGVGLGKTHLMHAVGHYVQQHKDNAKVMYLSSEKFTNEFISSIRDNKTEEFRTKYRNVDVL
>   LIDDIQFLAGKEGTQEEFFHTFNTLYDEQKQIIISSDRPPKEIPTLEDRLRSRFEWGLITDITPPDLETR
>   IAILRKKAKADGLDIPNEVMLYIANQIDSNIRELEGALIRVVAYSSLVNKDITAGLAAEALKDIIPSSKS
>   QVITISGIQEAVGEYFHVRLEDFKAKKRTKSIAFPRQIAMYLSRELTDASLPKIGDEFGGRDHTTVIHAH
>   EKISQLLKTDQVLKNDLAEIEKNLRKAQNMF

should be in row 1 of an excel sheet instead of first line on row 1, second line on row 2 etc etc

I HAVE NO IDEA HOW THIS IS HAPPENING.. I AM COPYING AND PASTING IT FROM HERE BUT SOMEHOW EACH SEQUENCE SEEMS TO COME ON THE SAME LINE WITH A LINE BREAK BETWEEN THEM WHICH I CAN EASILY REMOVE!!! Is there an alternative to copying off stack overflow??

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is. You just have to import it as a csv and set the delimiter to |. New lines will then just be taken as a new set in excel.

Comment: This seems to work in Excel for me. i just paste in the above, go to the data tab > text to columns and select '|' as the delimiter. It does seem to add a blank line in between each record, is that the issue?

Comment: If that's the issue, you can use notepad++ with extended find and replace to replace \n\r with nothing. Then import in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like SBI said, I edited it on textpad with regular expressions and it worked great.. I used the regular expression
\n^[a-z]
to remove the newline before each line of the sequence preserving the space between each new sequence id since the fasta format starts with > . Thx for the wonderful advice SBI. however, I cant seem to select yours as the best answer.

Comment: I actually did this in perl later since textpad was causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible by checking "other" as delimiter and then hold your alt-key and type 0010 in the textbox next to it .. you don't see any symbol, but it should work.